# Randomly loop through existing table column, to create fictitious data for another table

Tags: t-sql

I have a couple of tables with ten rows each, I want good tsql queries to build more rows on these specific tables.

I know RAND function works for selecting random int values.

```
CREATE Table Occupation
(
   Id int identity primary key,
   Designation nvarchar(50),
   country nvarchar(50)
)

Declare @Id int
Set @Id = 1

While @Id <= 10000
Begin 
   Insert Into Occupation values ('Designation - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)),
          'Country - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)) + ' name')
   Print @Id
   Set @Id = @Id + 1
End
```

but where Designation is I need it to randomly choose one of the below 
10000 times randomly or over and over until it reaches 10000

```
PK      Designation
---------------------------------------
1       Aquarium Process Controller
2       Assistant Plant Operator
3       Boilermaker
4       Casual
5       Casual laborer
6       Casual worker
7       Cat operator
8       Cleaner
9       FLOORS CLEANER
10      G foreman
```

Comment: I only see one table in your question. Check out Jeff Moden's [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for, first i create a temp table to store the data for the lookup table and query the temp table via a PK using a random number generated (between 1 and 10)

```
CREATE TABLE #tmpData (PK INT, Designation VARCHAR(64))

    INSERT INTO #tmpData (PK, Designation)
    VALUES (1, 'Aquarium Process Controller') -- add the rest of the records below (PK 2 to 10)

    CREATE Table Occupation
    (
       Id int identity primary key,
       Designation nvarchar(50),
       country nvarchar(50)
    )

    Declare @Id int
    Set @Id = 1

    DECLARE @Designation AS VARCHAR(64)

    While @Id <= 10000
    Begin 

       SET @Designation = 

    (SELECT Designation 
      FROM #tmpData 
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT RAND()*(11-0)+0) CxA(RandomNumber) -- creates a random number between 1 and 10
     WHERE PK  = CxA.RandomNumber)

       Insert Into Occupation values ( @Designation ,
              'Country - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)) + ' name')
       Print @Id
       Set @Id = @Id + 1
    End
```

Answer (score 1):

Loopless, 100% set-based solution. Ideas borrowed from Zohar Peled's comment on tally tables:

```sql
CREATE Table #Occupation
(
   Id int identity primary key,
   Designation nvarchar(50),
   country nvarchar(50)
);

DECLARE @designation TABLE
(   
    Designation nvarchar(50)
);

INSERT @designation (Designation) VALUES
     ('Aquarium Process Controller')
    ,('Assistant Plant Operator')
    ,('Boilermaker')
    ,('Casual')
    ,('Casual laborer')
    ,('Casual worker')
    ,('Cat operator')
    ,('Cleaner')
    ,('FLOORS CLEANER')
    ,('G foreman');

INSERT INTO #Occupation
SELECT tmp.Designation, 'Country' + CAST(NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY NEWID()) AS VARCHAR)
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP(10000) Designation
    FROM @designation
    CROSS JOIN [master].sys.all_columns ac1
) AS tmp;
```

The main trick, commonly used for obtaining 'random' records, is to order by `NEWID()`. Another trick is to group the records in 10 groups by `NTILE(10)` to get a number for the country name.

The `CROSS JOIN` is an idea from this tally-table link. It's simply a way to repeat a sequence of records by cross joining it with a ubiquitous table that has plenty of records. `TOP` prevents the cross join to be exhausted completely.